# Angular 8 - ngxTextHighlight

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-3

Caros,

Estou começando com Angular agora e fazia mto tempo que não desenvolvia para front-end. E estou com algumas dúvidas que gostaria de pedir ajuda a comunidade.

Então vamos lá.

Possuo uma página onde os dados são carregados pelo component principal. Esse component principal, monta um treeview ao lado esquerdo, onde, ao clicar em algum node da treeview os dados correspondentes ao item clicado são carregados ao lado direito, dentro de uma div conteúdo, carregada pelo component pesquisa. Esse componente pesquisa possui um input text, que tem a finalidade de pesquisar palavras dentro do conteúdo e destaca-las. Isso está funcionando perfeitamente, no entanto, ao digitar uma palavra que não existe ou apagar o conteúdo da campo pesquisar, os dados da div onde é exibido o conteúdo passar a exibir os dados entre as tags html e ao redigitar a uma palavra existente ele volta o conteúdo formatado.

Estou começando a entender o mecanismo da coisa. Já sei que o Angular trabalha com módulos e é componentizado e que os componentes podem conversar entre si intercambiando dados. Pois bem, o componente principal ele consome uma web API e carregado os dados do banco, dinamicamente, ele define onde cada dado será carregado. Neste caso em específico, ele passa os dados do conteúdo para o componente pesquisa. Porém no momento que eu digito algum valor que não exista no input de pesquiar ele perde o conteúdo passado pelo componente principal.

Acredito que para alguém que conheça bem a tecnologia deva ser algo simples de resolver.

Segue abaixo o trecho do códigos dos componentes citados:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input,Output,EventEmitter, SimpleChanges, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemExame, IgResult, Instrucoes } from '../IGInstrucoes';
import { DataServiceService } from 'src/app/data-service.service';
import { NodeClickEventArgs, NodeKeyPressEventArgs } from '@syncfusion/ej2-navigations';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'ig-principal',
  templateUrl: './principal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./principal.component.css'],

  //changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PrincipalComponent implements OnInit , OnChanges{
  order: string = 'nodeChild';
  reverse: boolean = false;

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  //console.log(changes)
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
}

  igResult : IgResult;
  @Input() conteudo = "";
  conteudo_auxiliar: string;
  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  showSpinner: boolean = true;
  public treeFields: Object;
  sortedCollection: any[];
  
  constructor(private data: DataServiceService)  {  alert('constructor - principal')}
  //constructor(private router: Router,private dataService: DataServiceService)  {  }
  
  CarregaNodes()
  {
    this.data.getList().subscribe((res) => {
      this.igResult = res;
      this.treeFields =
      {
        dataSource: this.igResult.nodes ,
        id: 'id',
        text: 'description',
        child: 'nodeChild'
        };
      });

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    alert('RDN: principal.component.ts/ngOnInit');
    //alert('RDN: principal.component.ts/ngOnInit: ' + this.conteudo);
    this.CarregaNodes();
  }  

  // enable the editing options to the TreeView
  public allowEditing: boolean = true;

  //Bind the nodeChecked event
  public nodeCheck(args: NodeKeyPressEventArgs | NodeClickEventArgs| any): void {

    //Recupera os Ids
    let checkedNode: any = [args.node.dataset];

    let ids: string =  checkedNode[0].uid;
    alert('RDN - 1: principalcomponents/nodeCheck -> ids: ' + ids);

    let split:string[] = ids.split('-');
    alert('RDN - 2: principalcomponents/nodeCheck -> split: ' + split);

    let idIg:number = Number(split[0]);
    alert('RDN - 3: principalcomponents/nodeCheck -> idIg: ' + String(idIg));

    let IgItem:number = Number(split[1]);
    alert('RDN - 4: principalcomponents/nodeCheck -> IgItem: ' + String(IgItem));

    let instrucao:Instrucoes = this.igResult.instrucoes.filter(f => f.id == idIg)[0];
    alert('RDN - 5: principalcomponents/nodeCheck -> f.id: ' + String(this.igResult.instrucoes.filter(f => f.id)[0].id));

    //instrucao.informacoesAdicionais.forEach( function(element){alert(element.linhas + '/' + element.titulo);})

    this.MontaTabelas(instrucao);

    alert('RDN - 6: principalcomponents/nodeCheck -> split.length: ' + String(split.length));
  
     if(split.length< 2){

      alert('RDN - 7: principalcomponents/nodeCheck -> split.length: IF');
      return;
    }
      
    let item: ItemExame = instrucao.descricaoItem.filter(f => f.idChave ==IgItem)[0];

    let retorno:string = '<h5>' + instrucao.description + '</h5>' + 
                         '<b>' + item.chave + '</b></br>' + item.valor + '<hr>';

    this.igResult.instrucoes.filter(f => f.id !=idIg).forEach(ig => {
      ig.descricaoItem.filter(f => f.chave ==item.chave).forEach(itemChave => {
        retorno += '<h5>' + ig.description + '</h5>' + 
                   '<b>' + item.chave + '</b></br>' + item.valor + '<hr>';
      });
    });

    let conteudo_auxiliar = retorno;
    this.conteudo = retorno;
  }

  private MontaTabelas(instrucao: Instrucoes) {

    const divRodape = document.getElementById('divRodape');
    let div: string = "<div>";
    let table: string = "";
    instrucao.informacoesAdicionais.filter(f => f.linhas.length > 0).forEach(informacao =>
    {
      "<span class='label label-default'>" + informacao.titulo + "</span>"
      informacao.linhas.forEach(linha => {
        
      table += linha;
    });
        
    div += "<b>" + informacao.titulo + "</b>";
    div += "<p class='text-justify'>" + table + "</p>";
     
    });
    div += "</div>";

    this.showSpinner = true;
    divRodape.innerHTML = div;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 border"> 
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
              <label class="form-check-label">Ordem Alfabética</label>
            </div>
            
            <div id='treeparent'>
              <ejs-treeview id='treeelement' [fields]='treeFields' (nodeClicked)="nodeCheck($event)" (keyPress)="nodeCheck($event)">
                <ig-loading-spinner *ngIf="showSpinner"></ig-loading-spinner>
                  {{ collection | orderBy: expression : reverse : caseInsensitive : comparator }}
              </ejs-treeview>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 border" style="max-height: 100%; height: 700px;">
          <ig-pesquisa [actualText]='conteudo'></ig-pesquisa>
        </div>
    
        <div id="divRodape" class="col-12 border" style="height: 80px;"> </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';
import { PrincipalComponent } from '../principal/principal.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataServiceService } from 'src/app/data-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ig-pesquisa',
  templateUrl: './pesquisa.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pesquisa.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class PesquisaComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges
{
  @ViewChild('dataContainer') dataContainer: ElementRef;

  ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges): void {
    //debugger ;
    //console.log(changes);
    
    alert('RDN - 1: ngOnChanges -> pesquisa.component.ts');
    this.html = this.actualText;

    this.dataContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.html;

    const divConteudo1 = document.getElementById('divConteudo');
    //divConteudo1.innerHTML = this.actualText;
    divConteudo1.nativeElement.innerHTML =  this.html;
    

    //alert(this.html);
  }

  @Input() html:string;
  @Input() actualText ='';
  @Input() conteudo: string;
  @Input() searchText: string;

  constructor(){
    alert('constructor - pesquisa');
    //console.log('RDN - 3: ngOnChanges -> pesquisa.component.ts');
    //alert('this.conteudo -> constructor: ' + 'constructor');
    //alert(this.html);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //alert('constructor - principal')
    //alert(this.html);
    //const val_pesquisa = (<HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById('pesquisa')).value;
    alert('RDN - 2: ngOnInit -> pesquisa.component.ts');
    //alert('val_pesquisa: ' + val_pesquisa);
    //alert('this.conteudo: ' + this.conteudo.toString);

    
  }
}

 /*
ngAfterContentInit(){alert('ngAfterContentInit');}
ngAfterContentChecked(){alert('ngAfterContentChecked');}
ngAfterViewInit(){alert('ngAfterViewInit');}
ngAfterViewChecked(){alert('ngAfterViewChecked');}
ngonDestroy(){alert('ngonDestroy');}
*/
```

```html
<input  class="form-control mr-sm-2"
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Pesquisar"
        aria-label="Search" 
        value="Pesquisar"
        [(ngModel)]="searchText"
        id="pesquisa"
>
<div #dataContainer
     id="divConteudo"
     ngxTextHighlight
     [content]=html
     [searchTerm]="searchText"
     [caseSensitive]="false">
</div>
```

Em anexo segue as fotos da sequencias dos fatos relatados.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Estou estudando o uso do behaviorsubject que parece atender o que necessito. Gostaria de saber se alguém tem conhecimento sobre?